# Creating links in tables with SQL field

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code for displaying results in a table. I am in need of a bit of help taking the ID from Tickets table and using it on the end of the hyperlink e.g. ".php?id=7"
I have been reading tutorials on this however things dont seem to be happening for me.
Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Site Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Quick Description</th><th>Contact</th><th>Status</th></tr>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(*credentials*);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE Status='Open' AND Active='active'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='//PHP/displayticket.php?id=$ID'>" . $row['ID'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SiteName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['quickdesc'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Contact'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please, remove your password from here and change it on the server!

Comment: I edited your post to remove credentials, but it could be safer to change it anyway on your server...

Comment: Agreed with blue. Change your login password asap!

Comment: *palm slaps face* ah... what a stupid mistake... thanks for editing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<td><a href='//PHP/displayticket.php?id={$row['ID']}'>" . $row['ID'] . "</a></td>";
```

Do you mean like this? Or am I not understanding your question?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

With:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ( $rows AS $row )
```